# DISM error 87, "The destination folder or file... does not exist". But, it does

Tags: batch, dism, microsoft

I'm trying to create a simple batch script to backup my drivers on any Windows PC. If I enter my script line-by-line in cmd it works fine, but when I run it as a batch script it gives me an error "destination folder or file ..... does not exist." Except that it does. Here's my script:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set timestamp=%date%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

set folder="C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\backups\drivers_%timestamp%"

mkdir %folder%

DISM /online /export-driver /destination:%folder%
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && setlocal

for /f ^eol^=^.^ ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=^4^ ^delims^=^<^>^. %%i in =;(`
     wmic.exe os get LocalDateTime /format:xml ^| find.exe "VALUE"
    `);= do set "_dt=%%~i" && set "_time=%time:~6,2%"

set "_timestamp=%_dt:~0,4%-%_dt:~4,2%-%_dt:~6,2% %_dt:~8,2%-%_dt:~10,2%-%_time%"

set "_folder="C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\backups\drivers_%_timestamp%""

mkdir %_folder% 
DISM /online /export-driver /destination:%_folder%

endlocal
```

---

- Results:

```bash
mkdir "C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\backups\drivers_2023-09-04 06-54-12"
DISM /online /export-driver /destination:"C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\backups\drivers_2023-09-04 06-54-12"
```

---

Your error refers to the character present in your layout for folder
name, precisely the `"/"` in `%timestamp%`/`%folder%`.

**[How do i get current date time on the Windows command line in a suitable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format?noredirect=1&lq=1)**
**[What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)**

---

**Obs.:** You get item in folders best listed and sorted ascending or descending if the names use numerical order in their name:

```all-bat
set "_folder="C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\backups\drivers_%_timestamp%""

...\drivers_2023-09-04 06-54-12
...\drivers_2023-08-31 21-01-08
...\drivers_2023-07-03 01-12-11
...

:: ... or 

set "_folder="C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\backups\%_timestamp%_drivers""

...\2023-09-04 06-54-12_drivers
...\2023-08-31 21-01-08_drivers
...\2023-07-03 01-12-11_drivers
```